# How to remove unused basicblocks llvm

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to remove unused blocks from llvm intermediate code.

First, I build a collection of reachable basicblocks, by starting with the entry basicblock and adding all basicblock successors from their terminator instruction:

```
bbset.insert(bbterm->getSuccessor(i));
```

After that, I iterate through the unreachable basicblocks and delete them using

```
DeleteDeadBlock(bb);
```

from Utils/BasicBlockUtils.cpp

It works, but in some scenarios I get a segfault. Below is the core dump:

```
opt: /home/user/llvm-3.3.src/lib/Transforms/Utils/BasicBlockUtils.cpp:38: void llvm::DeleteDeadBlock(llvm::BasicBlock*): Assertion `(pred_begin(BB) == pred_end(BB) || BB->getSinglePredecessor() == BB) && "Block is not dead!"' failed.
0  opt             0x0000000001756825 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*) + 38
1  opt             0x0000000001756aa2
2  opt             0x000000000175651e
3  libpthread.so.0 0x00007fe1fe76dbb0
4  libc.so.6       0x00007fe1fdbaef77 gsignal + 55
5  libc.so.6       0x00007fe1fdbb25e8 abort + 328
6  libc.so.6       0x00007fe1fdba7d43
7  libc.so.6       0x00007fe1fdba7df2
8  opt             0x000000000138b004 llvm::DeleteDeadBlock(llvm::BasicBlock*) + 139
9  opt             0x0000000000d49c2e
10 opt             0x0000000001652942 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) + 290
11 opt             0x0000000001652ab2 llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 84
12 opt             0x0000000001652dd0 llvm::MPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) + 502
13 opt             0x00000000016533a0 llvm::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 244
14 opt             0x00000000016535ab llvm::PassManager::run(llvm::Module&) + 39
15 opt             0x00000000008c6cb6 main + 5698
16 libc.so.6       0x00007fe1fdb99de5 __libc_start_main + 245
17 opt             0x00000000008b8a39
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a segfault, that's an assertion error, and it's telling you the problem: the predecessor list is not empty. You get this assertion error because `DeleteDeadBlock` verifies that the block you are deleting has no immediate predecessors (other than itself).

However, this test does not mean that the block is alive; for example, in this scenario (assume lines are downward-facing arrows):

```
entry
 /
A   B
|   |
C   D
 \ /
  E
```

B and D are both dead, but if you'll try to remove D before B you'll get the assertion since D has a predecessor (which isn't itself).

How to solve this? You can do one of:

1. Process the blocks in topological order
2. Remove all predecessors from the block you are about to delete (e.g. by replacing the terminator of all its predecessors with the `unreachable` instruction)

   - You can also do that to all the blocks you identify as dead first, and then delete them in arbitrary order

Comment: Oak, after deleting the blocks, I get some phinode instructions issues. After removing, say, block %1, a phi ins was replaced to %x = phi i32 [x, %label], [number, %0], and I get "PHINode should have one entry for each predecessor of  its parent basic block!" because %0 doesn't relate to the phi instruction. Do you what could be the problem?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky whenever you disconnect two basic blocks - alive or not - you have to update the phi nodes of the successor. `PHINode::removeIncomingValue` can help you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [llvm::EliminateUnreachableBlocks](https://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#a716fb64d05bc59a89aaa9d327c873c96). It performs a depth-first-search of basic blocks, starting at the entry block. This helps identify 'live' blocks that would become 'dead' once their 'dead' predecessors are removed.